# to_tsvector in simple mode throwing away non english in some setups

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

On some pg installs I am noticing the following happens

```
sam=# select '你好 世界'::tsvector;
   tsvector    
---------------
 '世界' '你好'
(1 row)

sam=# select to_tsvector('simple', '你好 世界');
 to_tsvector 
-------------

(1 row)
```

Even though my db is configured like so:

```
MBA:bin sam$ ./psql -l
                              List of databases
   Name    | Owner | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges
-----------+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 postgres  | sam   | UTF8     | en_AU.UTF-8 | en_AU.UTF-8 |
 sam       | sam   | UTF8     | en_AU.UTF-8 | en_AU.UTF-8 |
 template0 | sam   | UTF8     | en_AU.UTF-8 | en_AU.UTF-8 | =c/sam           +
           |       |          |             |             | sam=CTc/sam
 template1 | sam   | UTF8     | en_AU.UTF-8 | en_AU.UTF-8 | =c/sam           +
           |       |          |             |             | sam=CTc/sam
(4 rows)
```

On other similar setups I am seeing `select to_tsvector('simple', '你好 世界');` correctly return the tokens.

How do I diagnose the simple tokeniser to figure out why it is chucking out these letters?

Simplest repro seems to be installing postgres via postgres app. Does not happen when installing postgres on ubuntu with a locale set.

Comment: Please show the PostgreSQL versions on working and non-working setups. `SELECT version()`. It'd also be good to have the operating system. Also, make sure you're comparing the same thing - in some of your tests you have a space in the middle, in some not.

Comment: @CraigRinger I just don't know where to start here, how do I diagnose what tokens "simple" considers and what not. there must be some tables I can look into that explain how the simple tokeniser works.

Comment: The parser/tokeniser is the same for 'simple' and other languages. That's the dictionary configuration; it controls stemming and stop-words. The parser/tokeniser is written in C, and in the PostgreSQL sources. Now, please re-read my previous comment - you really need to check and see if the working and non-working setups have something different about them, starting with PostgreSQL version.

Comment: I can reproduce this with the exact same version, the difference is that initdb is triggered without a locale set anywhere in one case.

Comment: Can you show the different listings (`psql -l`) for the two cases then? You only show half the picture here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately, **default parser used by text search highly depends on the database initialization** and especially on `lc_collate` and the current database object encoding.

This is due to some inner working of the default text parser. It is vaguely [documented](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-parsers.html):

> Note: The parser's notion of a "letter" is determined by the database's locale setting, specifically `lc_ctype`. Words containing only the basic ASCII letters are reported as a separate token type, since it is sometimes useful to distinguish them.

The important part is these comments in PostgreSQL [source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL9_3_4/src/backend/tsearch/wparser_def.c#L430):

```
/* [...]
 * Notes:
 *  - with multibyte encoding and C-locale isw* function may fail
 *    or give wrong result.
 *  - multibyte encoding and C-locale often are used for
 *    Asian languages.
 *  - if locale is C then we use pgwstr instead of wstr.
 */
```

and below:

```
/*
 * any non-ascii symbol with multibyte encoding with C-locale is
 * an alpha character
 */
```

Consequently, if you want to use the default parser with Chinese, make sure your database is initialized with the C locale and you have a multibyte encoding, so all characters above U+007F will be treated as alpha (including spaces such as IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE U+3000 !). Typically, the following `initdb` call will do what you expect:

```
initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8
```

Otherwise, Chinese characters will be skipped and treated as blank.

You can check this with debug function `ts_debug`. With a database initialized with `lc_collate=en_US.UTF-8` or any other configuration where tokenization fails, you will get:

```
SELECT * FROM ts_debug('simple', '你好 世界');
 alias |  description  |   token   | dictionaries | dictionary | lexemes 
-------+---------------+-----------+--------------+------------+---------
 blank | Space symbols | 你好 世界 | {}            |            |
```

Conversely, with `lc_collate=C` and a UTF-8 database (initialized as above), you will get the proper result:

```
SELECT * FROM ts_debug('simple', '你好 世界');
 alias |    description    | token | dictionaries | dictionary | lexemes
-------+-------------------+-------+--------------+------------+---------
 word  | Word, all letters | 你好  | {simple}     | simple     | {你好}
 blank | Space symbols     |       | {}           |            | 
 word  | Word, all letters | 世界  | {simple}     | simple     | {世界}
```

It seems, however, that you mean to tokenize Chinese text where words are already separated by regular spaces, i.e. tokenization/segmentation does not happen within PostgreSQL. For this use case, **I strongly suggest using a custom parser**. This is especially true if you do not use other features of PostgreSQL simple parser, such as tokenizing URLs.

A parser tokenizing on space characters is very easy to implement. In fact, in [contrib/test_parser](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/test_parser/), there is a sample code doing exactly that. This parser will work whatever the locale. There was a buffer overrun bug in this parser that was fixed in 2012, make sure you use a recent version.

Comment: Wow, that's a mess. Looks like the text search engine really needs some love from someone who's into those languages.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer, this helps me a bunch.